# Java COM bridge

Tags: java, com, low-latency

I have an ultra-low latency program and need to interface with a Windows COM component. What would be the fastest way to do this? Using a COM bridge like JACOB or write a native COM library and send out messages using a messaging bus like ZeroMQ?

Comment: I can't really see why these two options would achieve the same. Can you better describe what you want to achieve? What's the COM component doing? Don't you have a result from the COM component that needs to be returned somewhere with a latency as low as possible?

Comment: Codo...I am receiving an event through the 3rd party COM component which I need to propagate to the Java program (the actual data is very small...just a few doubles). I need to do this as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ZeroMQ, you'll be dealing with two processes. And passing a message from one process to another is more expensive than doing the same within the same process. So using a Java COM bridge will certainly result in a lower latency.

Having said that, it's however only relevant if you're dealing with extermely low latency. If your COM component already has a latency several times higher than inter process message passing (e.g. because it is receiving and forwarding messages over a network or performing expensive computations), then either option will be okay because they both have a marginal effect on the overall latency.

Note that JACOB doesn't support all COM components, only those with a COM automation interface. So you might need to use a different Java COM bridge such as JCom.

Comment: Is the COM bridge definitely lower latency than using a native COM component and ZeroMQ with local messaging? I would have thought there would be some overhead in using COM within Java?

Comment: The overhead for in-process COM components is very low, and you have it in both setups, either in the Java process or the ZeroMQ process. The additional overhead for the Java-to-COM bridging depends on the bridging product you use but it should be similar to two or three calls to native code. So again: you either have it in the Java-to-COM bridge or when receiving a message from ZeroMQ. But the ZeroMQ solution definitely has the additional cost of sending a message, transmitting it to another process and doing the process context switch.