# How do I integrate Outlook into my Java desktop application?

Tags: java, desktop-application, outlook-2010

I want to integrate outlook in my desktop based java application. Can any one tell what are the solution for this. I have searched many items but they are paid service. is there any open source library which can do this? please help.

Regards.

Comment: Related to [Java COM bridge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298056/java-com-bridge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

[**Jinterop**](http://j-interop.org/) a Java Open Source library (under LGPL) that implements the DCOM wire protocol

or

[**JaWin**](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/) is a open source architecture for interoperation between Java and components exposed through Microsoft's Component Object Model (COM) or through Win32 Dynamic Link Libraries (DLLs).

Comment: thanks for reply. which one is comfortable for me here? if you say i can tell you my requirement. :|

Answer (score 2):

I used [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/) several years ago. It worked beautifully. The rather odd COM interface I was trying to use from Java presented some challenges, but JACOB was fabulous.